# How to query cloudwatch logs for successful lambda executions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

How can we get the minimum and maximum lambda execution time by querying cloudwatch? Note we only want to query for the successful execution and skip the failed ones.

This is my first attempt:

```
fields @message
| filter @type = "REPORT"
| stats min(@duration) as MinimumTime,
        max(@duration) as MaximumTime
```

Response:

[image: response]

It does generates the Min and Max execution time, but it includes the failed lambda executions.

**Partially working solution**: as the failed lambda executions has log both for `exception` and `report`; and successful execution only has `report`, the following query will remove the failed executions and list only the `requestId` of successful executions:

```
fields @message
| filter @message like "REPORT" or @message like "[ERROR]"
| filter ispresent(@requestId)
| stats count(*) as requestIdLogCount by @requestId
| filter requestIdLogCount == 1
```

Response:

[image: response]

Now is it possible to update the above query with some sort of subquery or something else where I can use the `@requestId` to filter out the log and generate report only with the successful lambda execution? Here is another query which is using the `@requestId` from above query

```
fields @message
| filter @type = "REPORT"
| filter @requestId in ["a458412a-95e7-5023-842e-1dbe8f58a876", "082db28d-8f43-5f83-9a72-ee1985861515"]
| stats min(@duration) as MinimumTime,
        max(@duration) as MaximumTime
```

Comment: Also be aware of [Lambda function metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-metrics.html) and the min/max statistics.

Comment: Thanks, but still trying to figure out the log query. Actually need to create cloudwatch dashboard with this matrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way would be to use [Lambda Metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-metrics.html) as suggested by @jarmond. CloudWatch metrics can easily used in CloudWatch Dashboards and are much, much faster to query (while also costing less).

Using the CloudWatch Logs query has a few caveats:

- Only 7 (IIRC) queries at the same time by default
- Takes some time to query/search the logs
- Billed by MB/scanned

So the best advice would be to use the provided metrics and if that doesn't suffice, only then use log file scanning.

Since you only want the successful invocations, the lambda function itself could write the metrics at the end of the request.

To the metrics query:

CloudWatch Logs can't cross reference other logs, so there is no sub-query functionality. You can only filter upon information in the same log line without cross-referencing other log lines.

If you *insist* in the use case, you would need to parse the logs yourself by using streams or log filters. General idea:

- Invoke log-specific-lambda upon successful invocation that is logged in CW logs
- Query CW Logs for the execution time and update a metric

Alternative would be to export CW Logs to S3 and use Athena or other products to do complex queries...